# How to prevent for recreate activity when navigation drawer menu click

Tags: android

In my application i don't want to recreate activity on navigation drawer menu click when i am on same activity.

user on map activity after navigation drawer item click map reloading. i don't want to reload map or refresh activity.

```
private void displayView(int position)
{
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:

            break;

        case 1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);

            startActivity(intent1);
            //finish();
            break;


        case 2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            finish();
            break;

        case 3:
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: 1) Please show your code. 2) The menu should be loading Fragments, not starting Activities

Comment: in my code i am using activity not fragment

Comment: Okay, please [edit] your question to include that code

Comment: you can used shared preference value to reload or recreate

Comment: i don't want to reload or recreate ABC

Comment: man i know what you ask but i am telling to you i.e. if you have in shared preference value in like intent4 then you no nee to call intent otherwise you need to have call the intent.

Comment: @MaheshGawhane i posted my answer below please accept it if it worked

Comment: why you unaccepted my answer after one year?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your function

```
private int current=-1;
    private void displayView(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
            current =0;
            break;

        case 1:
           if(current!=1){
            current =1;
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);

            startActivity(intent1);
            //finish();
            }
            break;


        case 2:
            if(current!=2){
            current=2;
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            finish();
            }

            break;

        case 3:
            if(current!=3){
            current=3
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
            finish();
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: thnks Mohammad Haidar

Comment: @MaheshGawhane Please accept my answer if it worked for you

Comment: Please update the post with a solution if you found it.